# Fedora kernel panic after system update

Tags: linux, fedora, automatic-update, dnf

I have Fedora 24 installed and it uses `packagekitd` to install updates when I shutdown the system.

It usually goes fine, but I left it running after work last Friday. When I came back today it was stuck at 97%, I performed a forced shutdown.

Now I get a kernel panic on boot, unless I choose the previous `grub` entry.  I performed `dnf clean && dnf update` but the issue persists. My understanding is the updated packages were corrupted.

I suppose the best approach would be to find which packages were installed between Friday and today and force a reinstall of all of them. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, obtain a list of your packages, sorted by install/update, with date included:

> ```
> rpm -qa --last
> ```

[(source)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86685/28160)

Take a note of the modules with an install date within the day of the crash.

Then you reinstall each of those modules with

> ```
> dnf reinstall <package>
> ```

Or, combine it all:

> ```
> dnf reinstall $(rpm -qa --last | grep "<localized date>" | cut -d " " -f 1)
> ```

Use the date of your update crash.

Answer (score 1):

Because using the previous grub entry works fine, the problem likely related to the latest kernel that was installed. I'm guessing that dracut failed for some reason. Uninstalling the most recent kernel should work. Something like this should do the trick:

```
dnf remove kernel-core-4.x.y
```

Where `4.x.y` is the version you want to uninstall. After that, `dnf update` should reinstall it for you. Then maybe you can see what is failing during the install.

Comment: Your answer would probably fix the kernel panic, but I prefer to reinstall all packages which were installed on the same date. This way, any possible corrupted package is overwritten with a correct copy.

Comment: The fact that a previous kernel works fine indicates that the other packages besides kernel related ones are not corrupt. You should focus on the kernel packages.

Comment: If you are truly worried about corruption mount the install from a live and `dnf history undo last ` and rerun the usual dnf update manually or with packagekit and if needed babysit it to see where and on what it hangs/was hung on.

Answer (score 0):

This is sample on fedora system ver 16 to 17. Follow your system.
Do as root login on temminal.

This command shows many duplicate packages (the same packages for fc16 and fc17).

```
rpm -qa | sort
```

Update a few packages missed the first time.

Here yum complained about duplicate packages.

```
yum --releasever=17 --disableplugin=presto distro-sync
```

This command removed 465 duplicates.

```
package-cleanup --cleandupes
```

This found no problems.

```
package-cleanup --problems
```

Remove new kernel

```
rpm -q kernel |grep fc17 | xargs rpm -e
```

Reinstall new kernel

Here I got the following error, which apparently was harmless.

> "grubby fatal error: unable to find a suitable template" yum upgrade

These commands are from the following URL # https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Upgrading_Fedora_using_yum

_Make_sure_Fedora_is_upgraded

```
/usr/sbin/grub2-install /dev/sda cd /etc/rc.d/init.d; for f in *; do [ -x $f ] && /sbin/chkconfig $f resetpriorities; done package-cleanup --orphans
```

Another way to solve this is to fresh install the system.

Comment: Much of this is obsolete with DNF in newer Fedora. Fedora 17 was retired in July, 2013, and a lot has changed in the last four years!